# How Do I Include PHP Strings In The Message Of The Mail() Function?

Tags: php, string, email

I'm trying to figure out how to include custom PHP strings in the message of the PHP mail function.

I have a user registration area on my website. Once a user signs up, I want to email them a success message, such as "Welcome to The site...." I want to include their name in the email, so I would need to pull the value from the field where they entered their name. I will be pulling over field values as well, but this is just an example.

I have:

```
$name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
$subject = 'Welcome!'
$message = '<HTML><body><p>Thank you for signing up' .$name. 'We are so glad that you are here</body></html>';
mail($email,$subject,$message);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what error/output are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

add header in your mail like this

```
$headers  = "From: myemail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: myemail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```